# How to set Max-width for <th> tag in Table, Does Max-width supports for <th>?

Tags: html, css

I was setting min-width and max-width to TH tag . Min-width property is reflecting where as max-width property is not reflected. When i inspect and check for the TH tag it looks applied only

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th> S.No </th>
    <th> Name </th>
    <th style="min-width:40px; max-width:150px;"> Description </th>
    <th> Gender </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> Xyz </td>
    <td> Having Excess content more than 160 characters </td>
    <td> Male/Female </t>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: max-width In table, can apply at all th tags. not any individual.

Comment: add `table { table-layout:fixed;}` and `th {max-width: 150px}`

Comment: murl2308 - that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Table columns will increased according to data

1. Inline width is not going to work
2. what you can do it put table-layout fixed `table(table-layout:fixed;)`
3. Then assign width to columns

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> S.No </th>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th style="width:150px; max-width: 150px;"> Description </th>
            <th> Gender </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> 1 </td>
            <td> Xyz </td>
            <td> Having Excess content more than 160 characters </td>
            <td> Male/Female </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If i give directly width:150px; then there is no case of min-width. Feild always occupies 150Px;

Comment: min-width:?? I have added max-width..as a precautionary measure..

Comment: If i have less content then ???

Comment: If you have less content, then it will fit inside 150px..but just in case if u need to print the page..thats precautionary measure...

Answer (score -2):

You can use below in your css for th and td tags

`max-width: 150px; 
word-wrap:break-word;`

However I think only `width` or with max-width should work too.

Comment: no luck dude... Until i use width it is not reflecting..